# WPF using Helix Tool, PropertyChangedEventHandler is always null while trying to update ModelVisual3D view

Tags: c#, wpf, helix-3d-toolkit

I am new to WPF and I am having issues trying to update the main window UI after a change.

I have the following MainWindow.xaml (I will show a part of it because it is large)

```
<Window
    x:Class="SimpleDemo.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:HelixToolkit="clr-namespace:HelixToolkit.Wpf;assembly=HelixToolkit.Wpf"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SimpleDemo"
    Title="Plot 3D data"
    Width="680"
    Height="680" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
```

Next important part is the 3D plot section of the MainWindow, where I Bind the Content of the plot with my Model3D object named as Model.

```
            <!--  Remember to add light to the scene  -->
            <HelixToolkit:SunLight />

            <!--  The content of this visual is defined in MainViewModel.cs  -->
            <ModelVisual3D Content="{Binding Path = Model, Mode=OneWayToSource,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

            <!--  You can also add elements here in the xaml  -->
            <HelixToolkit:GridLinesVisual3D
                Width="800"
                Length="800"
                MajorDistance="15"
                MinorDistance="15"
                Thickness="0.05" />

        </HelixToolkit:HelixViewport3D>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Margin="5" Click="Backward_Click">Backward</Button>
            <Button Margin="5" Click="Forward_Click">Forward</Button>
        </StackPanel>
```

The idea of the program is to read the first 500 data points (x,y,z) from a txt file and then creating a AddRectangularMesh() from those using Helix Toolkit. I do this for multiple set of points and I finally have a mesh with multiple AddRectangularMesh() objects. After that, I display the final result to the HelixViewport3D.
In the UI I have two buttons Forward and Backward. The forward button is trying to draw the next 500 points from the txt file.

In my MainWindow.xaml.cs file I call the Event handlers of the buttons which calls the Functions in MainViewModel.cs file where all the functions for that data points are calculated and the final result will be saved on Model3D Model object, and then must be drawn on the UI.

Button calls the Forward_click event and Increases the counter to read the next data points

`<Button Margin="5" Click="Forward_Click">Forward</Button>`

After I press the button the Event Handlers is called but it is null, so the UI is never update and I can't show the next data points.
In my code I have implemented the Event handler, to listen on the changes of the Model, so after the execution of the functions the model object will be updated and then call the handler to update the UI.

The MainViewModel Class is defined as:

```
    public class MainViewModel : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
```

and the event handlers as below:

```
        private Model3D model;
        public Model3D Model 
        { 
            get { return model; }
            set 
            {
                model = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Model));
            } 
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, e);
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
```

I put breakpoints on the code, and when I press the Button, the handler is called but is null and then nothing is updated or done, the function calculates the new Model3D object with new points, but does not draw the new result.

If I run the same function on `public MainViewModel()` section the first 500 points are shown, but it due to the first run of the window.

This is how the Model object is updated after each button press.

```
public void CoreCalculations()
        {
            for (int i = 0 ; i < 500; i++)
            {
                //read File Line
                // --- Do something with the points ---
                // create a mesh using the points and AddRectangularMesh
            }
            MeshGeometry3D mesh = meshBuilder.ToMesh(true);
            Material blueMaterial = MaterialHelper.CreateMaterial(Colors.Blue);
            modelGroup.Children.Add(new GeometryModel3D { Geometry = mesh, Transform = new TranslateTransform3D(2, 0, 0), Material = blueMaterial, BackMaterial = blueMaterial });
            Model = modelGroup;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `OneWayToSource` to `OneWay`. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindingmode?view=windowsdesktop-5.0)

> Updates the source property when the target property changes.

And you probably want to do it the other way around. Update the target whenever the model changes.

It is a bit odd that `MainViewModel` inherits from `Window`. I would suggest taking a look at the helix3D "SimpleDemo". Just to confirm that changing the model works, Make the mainViewModel inherit INotifyPropertyChanged, and add the following code:

```
        private async Task RemoveModel()
        {
            await Task.Delay(5000);
            Model = null;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Model));
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
```

And call `RemoveModel` in the constructor. That should make the model be removed after 5s. Note that the example code is suitable for debugging, and nothing else.

You should also be able to use the [live visual tree explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/inspect-xaml-properties-while-debugging?view=vs-2019) to help debug the UI.

Comment: I did change the Mode to OneWay but still the debug says the handler is null and nothing is updated on the UI.
I had the idea to do something like MainWindow.Refresh after the Core function executes but I didn't find any method for this purpose.

Comment: @FosDrogg Gmr added some notes about other things that might be incorrect.

Comment: Yes, I thought the same about the MainViewModel : Window, but the sample project was taken from the original Helix Toolkit github example program. I tried to add mine features inside of it. Maybe something with the DataContext is not working properly and I cannot get the Data shown to main window?

Comment: Your final answer helped me a lot to reconsider my code. I combined your idea with mine and I managed to create the function I needed to add more points into my 3D view. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I tried something else, if I call the RemoveModel task inside the MainViewModel constructor the program clears the 3D plot as expected, BUT if I call the RemoveModel task after the constructor finished execution nothing changes and the event handler is null.

Comment: @Fosdrogg Gmr Are you sure you are not doing something weird like using background threads? Or have multiple objects and are changing the wrong one (use "[make object id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-tips-and-tricks?view=vs-2019)" to check)? Because I fail to see how it should matter if you call it in the constructor or not.

Comment: I have added a button on the UI to call ButtonClear function which then calls the RemoveModel.
You can see the code on this link: https://gist.github.com/nikossoultanis/671b188135b20eb2b96d09c5ce6f09c6
Am I doing something that i missing that messes up the Model?

Comment: I think I found what I messed up. In order to call a function on MainWindow class from MainViewModel, I create an instance of MainViewModel and I create a new object which messes up all the other objects.